# Can I run lines in python as in R?

Tags: python, r

I would like to know if I can execute some lines of my script instead of all the code, as in R.

Example:

```
print ("hello world")
print ("How old are you?")
```

I want to print just line one, How?

Comment: use the terminal or something like jupyter

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please tell us the *actual* full problem. It seems you need logical conditioning to execute *some* and not *all* lines.

Comment: In fact I just want to run parts of the code without run the whole code, as in R. That's becase at the begining I have to read a lot of data and takes me much time run all when I just want to see one part. I can't use jupyter, I have to use Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions:

```
def actionsToDo():
  print("You can see me")

def actionsToSkip():
  print("You can't see me")

actionsToDo()
```

You can also call `exit()` and this will terminate the execution of the script, but this is not a good practice.

```
print("You can see me")
exit()
print("You can't see me")
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem at all